# How to use the Steam overlay in StarCraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to use the Steam overlay in StarCraft II? I tried adding it to Steam, but the overlay closes whenever I hit "Play" from the launcher. I tried running Steam as admin too, but that didn't help. Is there someway to use get it to run in-game?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get it through the patcher, but you can *skip* the launcher by adding `<C:\Program Files>\StarCraft II\Support\SC2Switcher.exe` to Steam. This won't check for patches though, so you should run the patcher separately before you open the game in Steam.

Comment: I can confirm this to work, even with the Battle.net launcher as of patch 2.1.12.